# "Docky needs composition enabled" message even after I enabled that, in Xubuntu

Tags: 12.04, xfce, docky, lxde

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Xubuntu-desktop because I need to use Xubuntu sometimes .I have installed Docky for quick access . But i am not getting it properly because of the error . details you can find in image i have uploaded . i have enabled composite already but still i got this .

EDIT: Same problem with Lubuntu Environment also . How can i solve this .

.[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### enabling docky effects in xfce

By default, Docky should work with the built-in XFCE/Xubuntu compositor.

In 12.04 the compositor can be checked (if it is not already) via the window-manager tweaks

[image]

The image above shows Docky does not have the 3D effects, but by checking the options you'll have the 3D effects as per the next image:

[image]

If, for whatever reason the inbuilt compositor does not work for you, you'll need another compositor to help out Docky.

### alternative method for both XFCE/LXDE

A good lightweight compositor is `xcompmgr`

#### [xcompmgr](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xcompmgr) [image: Install xcompmgr]

[image]

As the image above shows, the inbuilt compositor is not running.  `xcompmgr` is running, which gives Docky the 3D effects you require.

Use *session and startup* to run `xcompmgr` when you login.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=325tdNpacuo) or [this alternative](http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/make-xfce4-bottom-dock-act-like-docky-awn/).

I dont use `xfce` but I understand it has a dock by default.