# How to enable composition for Lxde?

Tags: docky, lxde, compositing

I have had the same problem in Xubuntu as documented in

- ["Docky needs composition enabled" message even after I enabled that, in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169687/docky-needs-composition-enabled-message-even-after-i-enabled-that-in-xubuntu)

But now I am facing the same issue in Lubuntu as well. I can't find "Enable display compositing" in Lubuntu though.

Look at the image for the error message:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Docky needs composition enabled" message even after I enabled that, in Xubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169687/docky-needs-composition-enabled-message-even-after-i-enabled-that-in-xubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lubuntu, does not use Composition, you can a very basic compositing manager in the form of `xcompmgr` just make it auto start when you log in.

`sudo apt-get install xcompmgr` will Install it.

Answer (score 1):

XCompMgr works, but a great alternative is `compton`.

To install, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:richardgv/compton  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compton
```

and then

```
sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

and add the line

```
@compton -c -r 16 -l -24 -t -12 -G -b
```

Then reboot and you should be good to go.