# Xubuntu Netflix compositing issues?

Tags: xubuntu, compositing, netflix-desktop

I’ve got this error message while trying opening Netflix on Xubuntu, Compositing is not available, please enable compositing support and relaunch Netflix Desktop. Ive verified online their isnt any resources available out there for my problem, and there is nothing that had worked yet... So any how-tos, or instructions to solve this problem will be appreciated. Thnxs in advance!! ;)

Comment: that shows you how to enable "composting" follow this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/169757/47291

Comment: I tried it, and it didnt work either...